# How to restore no longer available app from iCloud Backup

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup

I had to restore my iPhone from iCloud backup. Unfortunately some of my apps are stuck on "Waiting.." stage. One of them is very important for me, it's Stash (http://hedonicsoftware.com/stash.html). It's an application to store documents, photos with password. I tried to find it under App Store -> Purchased tab, but it's not there. I have very important stuff in this app, so I would like to restore the application or the data. I think the app data should be in the cloud, but I can't read/download this data without the app.

What can I do? (I have the latest iOS)

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever sync or backup to iTunes? If you could restore from backup from iTunes that wouldn't be a problem, but short of that you could still see if it has the app you could copy to your phone. Not sure if that would include the documents and data though.

If by any chance that app syncs over iCloud or some other cloud service, the raw files may still be accessible (but still likely encrypted).

I personally would contact the app developers and see if they have any ideas.